# Как обработать форму, чтоб получить данные из нее и обновить?

Tags: ajax, yii

Yii. Есть кнопка, которая вызывает форму еще с одной ajax-кнопкой. Потом эта форма должна убраться.

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {

        $id_div = $_POST['id_update_div'];

        $model = new Answers_Objects;

        echo $id_div;

        echo CHtml::beginForm());
        echo CHtml::label('Содежимое ответа:', 'answer');
        echo CHtml::textArea('answer','',array('cols'=>'100','rows'=>'10'));

        echo CHtml::ajaxButton('Ответить',
                CController::createUrl('/reviews_objects/answer_submit'),
                array(
                        'type' => 'POST',
                        'data'=>array(
                                'update'=>TRUE,
                                //передаем id отзыва
                                'id_review_object'=>$_POST['id_review_object'],
                                'id_update_div'=>$id_div,
                                'value' => "$('form').serialize()"
                        ),
                        'dataType' => 'html',
                        'update'=>'#'.$id_div
                ),
                array(
                        'type'=>'submit'
                )
        );

        echo CHtml::endForm();

    }
```

Так вот, как обработать эту форму, чтоб получить данные из нее и обновить

```
<div id=$id_div>
```

?

Пробовал в `action` тега `form` указать `CController::createUrl('/reviews_objects/answer_submit')`, но тогда `div` не обновляется, а с нуля выводятся мои `echo` в обработчике.

---

Уточнение :

Ajax-кнопка изначально, т.е. div обновляется кодом выше:

```
<div id="answer_number_3"> //его надо обновить
  <input id="answer_3" type="button" value="Ответить на отзыв" name="yt2">
</div>
```

Здесь вопросов нет - форма появляется. Поэтому код кнопки приводить не буду.

Вот получившаяся форма после нажатия:

```
<div id="answer_number_3"> //его надо обновить снова
  <form method="post">
    <label for="answer">Содежимое ответа:</label>
    <textarea id="answer" name="answer" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
    <input id="yt0" type="submit" value="Ответить" name="yt0">
  </form>
</div>
```

Если оставить action пустым, то запрос на /reviews_objects/answer_submit не приходит, а форма пытается обработаться текущим адресом/контроллером, в котором это не предусмотрено и вылазит пустая страница. Получается, что параметр action в теге form приоритетнее ajax : url ?

Comment: поясните пожалуйста - это код представления вы я так понимаю привели?

Comment: @Ale_x, это код контроллера, который вызывается при нажатии на ajax-кнопку. Т.е. есть изначально кнопка. Нажимаем на нее - появляется форма ввода (код выше). Затем данные ввода (записываются в БД) становятся вместо этой формы ввода. С кнопки вызывается форма ввода без проблем по коду выше. А вот обработать эту форму не получается. Div, указанный в 'update' => '#$id_div' не обновляется из указанного /reviews_objects/answer_submit... Там пока просто echo 'otvet';

Answer (score 1):

Видимо придется решать так:

```
$(function()
        {
            $(function()
            {
                $('#test_form').submit(function(eventObject)
                {
                    //отменяем стандартное действие при отправке формы
                    eventObject.preventDefault();
                    //берем из формы метод передачи данных
                    var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
                    //получаем адрес скрипта на сервере, куда нужно отправить форму
                    var m_action=$(this).attr('action');
                    //получаем данные, введенные пользователем в формате input1=value1&input2=value2...,
                    //то есть в стандартном формате передачи данных формы
                    var m_data=$(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: m_method,
                        url: m_action,
                        data: m_data,
                        success: function(result){
                            $('#answer_form').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Хотя даже так данные (например data: m-data) не отправляются. Приходится через hiddenField "прикручивать", а значения ввода получать через $_POST. Т.е. по сути, просто отменили обновление страницы.

Криво, но вроде работает...

Answer (score 0):

Тогда вам надо прочитать про паттерн [MVC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) - разберетесь, и тогда все встанет на свои места - код раскидаете по нужным местам.

Comment: Да читал я... Просто не понимаю почему ajax не срабатывает. В коде выше если сделать так:  
  
    echo CHtml::beginForm(CController::createUrl('/reviews_objects/answer_submit'));  
  
То содержимое придет, но это будет не ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Давай по порядку

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton('Ответить',
```

firebug что пишет на это? Отсылается запрос на **/reviews_objects/answer_submit** если да то далее отсылаются ли параметры туда

```
  'data'=>array(
                              'update'=>TRUE,
                              'value' => '$form.serialize()'
                                      ),
```

Дальше буду обновлять ответ по мере комментариев от тебя.

В POST попадает 'update'=>'#'.$id_div?

если попадает то

```
'update'=>'#'.$id_div
```

заменить на

```
 'update'=>'#answer_number_'.$id_div
```

тогда должен обновиться этот див. Это если передается только ID

Comment: @Shrek, уточнил

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: @Shrek, насколько я понимаю проблема в следующем. Отправка ajax не происходит впринципе. Данные ввода ВСЕГДА отправляются в action тега form. Если не укажу action - будет текущим контроллером обрабатываться, укажу - теряется страница, ибо это не ajax. Такое ощущение, что url: из ajax просто игнорируется...  
  
Поэтому про проблему update говорить еще рано. Проблема, что не приходят $_POST['value'] и др. из поля data. А только $_POST['answer'] - имя textArea.  

П.С. $id_div = 'answer_number_3' Там к answer_number_ присоединяется id из БД.

Comment: preventDefault?